# Polynomial with two double roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

I need to find $a$, $b$ real numbers such that the polynomial $P(x)=x^{4}-4 x^{3}+10 x^{2}+a x+b$ has 2 double roots. I have tried this $P^{\prime}(x)=4 x^{3}-12 x^{2}+20 x+a=0$ but I still have a so I cant find roots. I know I can write this polynomial as (x-A)^2*(x-B)^2 where A and B  are 2 double roots but I don't know how to proceed from here?

Comment: Yes thank you I will try to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $P(x)$ has two double roots. Then, as you said, $P(x)=(x-A)^2(x-B)^2$. Multiply out the brackets and expand. Then you can compare the coefficients of the polynomials (you will get $4$ simultaneous equations) from which you can immediately solve for $a,b$.